# how do you loop through a list of deep stacked folders and move all the files to one specific folder in unix?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

I downloaded a bunch of images files but they are ordered recursively by month and day so there is a folder and a file for the day of the month, I am trying to loop through all the files found by the find command and move them to just one folder in my home directory.
mv `find ~/Downloads/skydrive* -name *.jpg` -exec mv ~/temp {} \;

it's not working it says directory doesn't exist, I have also tried a for loop but I get the same result.
any light on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something looks wrong about "mv dest src". Also, consider when the filename contains spaces ..

Comment: can you use $1 as a variable for the input source?

Answer (score 3):

You were close - you just got the arguments to [mv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) in the wrong order - try:

```
$ find ~/Downloads/skydrive* -name \*.jpg -exec mv {} ~/temp/ \;
```

Comment: I have tried that the exit status is 0 but all I get is a unix file called temp, instead of all the images in the folder temp

Comment: Make sure you actually have a directory at `~/temp`. Also note that I've now added a trailing `/` to `~/temp/` to make sure you don't write a file if it's missing.

Answer (score 1):

try to put your name between single quotes: 
find '~/Downloads/skydrive*' -name '*.jpg' -exec mv ~/temp {} \;

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done if your shell is bash version 4+ (which I believe is the case on OSX) using the globstar shell option and a for loop:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ~/Downloads/skydrive/**/*.jpg; do mv "$f" ~/temp/; done
```

This will break if you have several hundred thousand jpg files, while the `find` solutions won't, but for anything else it should work perfectly well.

Comment: I don't know about 10.9, but the latest public version of OS X (10.8) still comes with bash 3.2.